# Swift package manager error: NoSources

Tags: linux, swift, swift-package-manager

I am adding a dependency Package, and I am getting this error at build time:

```
error: NoSources("[...]/Tests/TestResources")
```

Please tell me how to get past this error. Is there a way to instruct SPM not to go into the `Tests` for a specific dependency? A package-specific `exclude: []` statement or something.

```
$ swift --version
Swift version 3.0-dev (LLVM b361b0fc05, Clang 11493b0f62, Swift 24a0c3de75)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have `exclude` directive in Package.swift - https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/Package.swift.md

It seems you are using the snapshot of swift of March 1st, there is a defect in this version regarding excluding files in Tests https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-864. It is solved in the later versions, so you can switch to a newer version, the last one is of 24-th of March.

As a temporarily workaround, if you still want to use your current version of swift, you can just move `TestResources` out of `Test` directory.